# Amazon ec2 instance slow

Tags: amazon-ec2

The instance started to fail on mysql... the mysql stops from nowhere. Then i was re-starting it and it worked again.

But now, it got worse. The transfer rate when i download a file from another instante starts in 900kbps and keep going down till 20kbps. Also for external downloads.

I tested also a zip job, zipping a big file.... it starts quickly then it slows down and keeps a rate of 10 files zipped per second wich is too slow ( another instances gets 1000 files per sec).

I can't access trough http the websites hosted also because its too slow.

I have already reboot, stop->start. Also i made an image e rebuild the image in a new instance and the problem continues. I also changed the Volume used by the instance and the volume with the problem keeps slow.

What should i do?

Comment: Can you tell us the current status of the instance? Disk state? Health of the hardware? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_ec2.html

Comment: What size is your instance?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab (based on the lack of details), that your instance is just to small - sounds like you are running a web server and mysql on it at least, I'll also bet that you are trying to use a micro instance which have notoriously variable performance statistics and really aren't suitable for running a web server and database server with consistent performance (maybe ok for development, but not production imo).

Try just spinning up a larger instance and see if your problems magically go away; you can test this for a few dollars and if it does solve the problem you can decide if you can permanently upgrade the image size.